# Linear Logistic Regression where Dummy variable is strictly dependent of other covariates

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, interaction

I want to do a logistic regression for something being granted or not.
In this I have independent variable that is dependent of a dummy variable. 
For example,

I want to regress

```
glm(granted ~ age + score + coperson + coscore + , family=binomial(logit))
```

Here, "coperson" is a dummy variable and "coscore" is dependent of "coperson". So if coperson is 1, then coscore has a value (any continuous value, from 0.0 to 100.0)
But I feel that this setting of regression is incorrect. If coperson = 0, then "coscore" should have a "hole" right?
Should I write the equation in another form? Like interactions?

Comment: So `coperson` is an indicator, `I(coscore > 0)`?

Comment: Coperson is a dummy. If there is a coperson then it's 0, otherwise 1. Coscore is dependent of coperson. If Coperson is 1, then coscore is a score for the coperson in question.

Comment: Then I think you want `granted ~ age + score + coperson + coscore + ` so you have a linear function of `coscore` when it exists, and a constant factor when it doesn't exist. That is, what you have seems fine to me.

Comment: Even though coscore is dependent of coperson? For instance if coperson = 1, then coscore can be say coscore = 23.4. If or another hand coperson = 0, then coscore = 0. (In my RAW data, for coperson = 0, my coscore = "NULL" and not coscore = 0). But you the model is still valid?

Comment: I am a little confused now, you said "If there is a coperson then it's 0, otherwise 1", is this correct?

Comment: Oh sorry. In my RAW data: If coperson = 1, then coscore = any number from 0.0 to 100. Otherwise if coperson = 0, then coscore = "NULL". This is because there IS no coperson and there is in that case no value for coscore. I assumed to make all "NULL" to 0 before but I think this a wrong method doing. Since the dependence of coperson and coscore. In my case there is a "hole" in coscore when coperson = 0. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22236/discussion-between-jeff-and-elekko).

Comment: Sounds like the factor coscore is nested in the factor coperson. 

Depending on the software you're using this will look like:
`granted ~ age + score ... + (coperson | coscore)`

Not quite sure how the model will like no variation on one of the factors, which makes me hesitate a little. 

Also sorry for being a couple years late for you, but perhaps it helps someone else.